# Angular BehaviorSubject Data Service > issue with nested data

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have been using an Observable as a Data Service for my app and recently came up with an "error". I have a main BehaviorSubject object that holds my main model and I create additional nested Observables on nested properties of the main Model with **distinctUntilChanged** (so I can easily subscribe to changes only to those child properties).

My service exposes methods to update nested data. I am able to update the data without issues, but the **problem is that the nested Observable doesn't trigger the update on the detail$ subscription** (see TAP2 comment below).

I believe that is due to the fact that I am getting the value from the main BehaviorSubject and updating it directly before emitting the next value. I know that if I copy the object and then update and emit it works, but I'm no sure if it is the best way to accomplish it.

**Is there a different (better) way to implement it? I really prefer having a single BehaviorSubject to hold my data, and that was the best way I could figure out how to do it without having to deep clone the object.**

I created a stackblitz with working sample:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/components-issue-trqau3

And here's my code:

**Model**

```
export interface MyModel {
  name: string;
  detail: MyModelDetail;
}
export interface MyModelDetail {
  brand: string;
  items: any[];
}
```

**Service**

```
export class MyServiceService {

  private _data = new BehaviorSubject<MyModel>(null);
  public data$ = this._data.asObservable();

  public detail$ = this.data$
    .pipe(
      map(a => a.detail),
      tap(a => console.log('tap1', JSON.stringify(a))),
      distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => {
        let dist = JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b);
        return dist;
      }),
      tap(a => console.log('tap2', JSON.stringify(a))), //TAP 2 doesn't get called
    );

  public init(data: MyModel) {
    this._data.next(data);
  }

  public updateDetail(detailData: MyModelDetail) {
    let data = this._data.getValue();

    data.detail.items.push(...detailData.items);
    this._data.next(data); //Tap 2 doesn't get called
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
export class AppComponent {
  data$: Observable<MyModel> = this.service.data$;
  detail$: Observable<MyModelDetail> = this.service.detail$;
  constructor(private service: MyServiceService) {
    service.init({
      name: 'test',
      detail: {
        brand: 'apple',
        items: ['imac']
      }
    });
  }

  updateDetail() {
    this.service.updateDetail({
      brand: 'google',
      items: ['iphone']
    });
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: @JasonGoemaat yes. If I update the value of the **_data BehaviorSubject** on the **updateDetail** method on the service. The change isn't notified to the **detail$ objservable** due to the distinctUntilChanged

Answer (score 1):

The data is pointing to the same data Object reference, so if you updated it, it also update the data stored in `BehaviorSubject`. So `distinctUntilChange` is always comparing the same object. You need to create a new data object like below (could be less performant) Or make sure you always create immutable data object.

```
 public updateDetail(detailData: MyModelDetail) {
    let data = this._data.getValue();
    data=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
    data.detail.items.push(...detailData.items);
    this._data.next(data);
  }
```

Comment: I did that in a different case, but I wonder if that is the best approach to handle the data. Do you recommend a different way to work this out? Not sure if the single behavior subject is the way to go or not.

Comment: You can create a state machine in rx pretty easier, it needs a behavior subject and an observable together

Answer (score 0):

In Angular comparisons are made with object references. So when you change the nested properties the change is not triggered. Only first childs trigger a change event. You'll need to create a new object and then pass it to the the `BehaviorSubject`. You can use `lodash` `cloneDeep` to perform a deep copy of an object.

```
import {cloneDeep} from lodash;

     public updateDetail(detailData: MyModelDetail) {
        const data = cloneDeep(this._data.getValue());
        data.detail.items.push(...detailData.items);
        this._data.next(data);
      }
```

Comment: Does it perform better than JSON.stringify/parse? Do you have a suggestion for a different(better?) way to handle the data? That was the best way I could find to accomplish what I wanted...

Comment: Here you can check different cloning techniques performances. It's interesting have a look. JSON.parse/JSON stringify seems to be the slowest  https://jsperf.com/deep-copy-vs-json-stringify-json-parse/5